# Asp.net website compatibility with IE 11

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have an old asp.net intranet website.. I have been using IE 8 till now without any issue. Now I am trying to check if it works well with IE 11. I see that there is no problem with the site when requesting the page from IE 11 from my desktop.

But when I try to debug the same website locally in VS the controls are out of place and even fails to detect the IE Browser by 
if(window.ActiveObject) which seems to be correct behaviour for IE 11.

Now I am wondering how the intranet website looks perfectly fine in IE 11. The server is Windows server 2008 IIS 7.

Any suggestion.

Comment: You are may browsing in compatibility mode.

Comment: Yes. Display intranet sites in compatibility view was checked

Answer (score 0):

The window.ActiveXObject property is hidden from the DOM starting from IE11 so, you can no longer use it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn423948%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

In VS, it happens often to see the markup misaligned whenever in designer mode. But I think you should care less about that and focus more on the code markup instead

Answer (score 0):

In the web config file you can use the customHeaders tag:

```
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <httpRedirect enabled="false" />
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <remove name="X-UA-Compatible" />
            <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=EmulateIE7" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```